# Partial specialization of template template parameters, with varying number of parameters

Tags: c++, templates

If the title doesn't make sense, here's the gist of the problem:

```
template <template <class> class ContainerOf>
class Foo;

template <>
class Foo<boost::optional> // works!
{
    // ...
};

// ERROR! std::vector takes two parameters
// T and Alloc.
template <>
class Foo<std::vector> 
{
    // ...
};
```

In essense I want to specialize for various templates, that take a single type parameter. However, many templates in STL and elsewhere have other parameters such as Allocators, and Compare operations (e.g. std::map). I don't care about those. I want to specialize for a std::vector with a "hole" where T is.

Thoughts? I feel like I need some kind of wrapper objects, or some sort of indirection to achieve this - it would also probably change the way the user instantiates these templates.

Comment: is `template <typename <class> class ContainerOf>` a typo?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. And, if my understanding is right, I'll tell you the easiest way is to accept a pair of iterators (range) since that's the way most functions/classes work in C++.

Comment: @black Unfortunately that is not what I'm trying to do. This is a very condensed form of my problem, but I need to create traits classes for a set of different containers. Allows me to do `foo_traits<std::vector>::bar` to query certain properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 you can use variadics:

```
template <template<typename T, typename...> class ContainerOf> 
class Foo;
```

Comment: Apparently `template <template<typename...> class ContainerOf>` also works (which is what I'm going with)! I was convinced this wouldn't work because I thought it would only accept variadic templates. Didn't even think of trying it :) Thanks